# React MSAL bearer token authentication for 2 APIs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, bearer-token, msal

I wonder how to implement a React MSAL custom hook. The problem is, I'm trying to get the bearer token in an axios interceptor. But any request my React makes disappears just after the `useMsal()` call. Thanks for any help.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useIsAuthenticated, useMsal } from '@azure/msal-react';
import config from '../../config';
export const useMsalToken = () => {
   const { instance, accounts } = useMsal();
   const isAuthenticated = useIsAuthenticated();
   const [token, setToken] = React.useState<{ token: string, expiresOn: Date | null } | null>(null);
   const refreshToken = async () => {
       if (!isAuthenticated || !Array.isArray(accounts) || accounts.length === 0) return;
       const { 0: account } = accounts;
       try {
           const response = await instance.acquireTokenSilent({
               scopes: [`api://${config.azureAd.clientId}/user_impersonation`],
               account
           });
           const { accessToken, expiresOn } = response;
           if (accessToken && accessToken.length > 0) {
               setToken({
                   token: accessToken,
                   expiresOn
               });
           }
       }
       catch (err: any) {
           if (err &&
               (err.errorCode === 'consent_required' ||
                   err.errorCode === 'interaction_required' ||
                   err.errorCode === 'login_required' ||
                   err.errorCode === 'invalid_grant')) {
               instance.loginRedirect();
           }
       }
   };
   React.useEffect(() => {
       refreshToken();
   }, [accounts, isAuthenticated]);
   if (token && token.expiresOn != null) {
       const currentDate = new Date();
       if (token.expiresOn.getTime() < currentDate.getTime()) {
           setToken(null);
           refreshToken();
       }
   }
   return token != null ? token.token : '';
};
```

I tried fetching MSAL token in order to add it to headers for API calls. Unfortunately, I can't understand why not a single http request appears in my web browser. I expected to view those requests in debug.

Comment: If the meal cache already has an access token with the appropriate scopes that hasn’t expired, it won’t make a request for one unless you supply the forceRefresh:true option when requesting the token

Comment: Token expiry and management is handled automatically by MSAL, I’d remove all the logic around expiry, and token state and just make a request to MSAL every time. Theres a ton of code that doesn’t serve any purpose because MSAL has its own cache and expiry management. It even automatically refreshes the token if it determines it’s needed. Just make a request to MSAL for an access token and let MSAL do the rest

Comment: Thanks @AdamJenkins, I've taken your comments into account. Then I made an Axios interceptor that calls an async getToken function. I'm not using useMsal hook but instead I'm using my MSAL instance declared in my index.ts.

Comment: Interceptor is the way to go, @Flo! Nice and simple.